# Changing the attributes of a header, based on values selected from a form

Tags: html, css, forms

I have to implement a form in html with 3 select attributes(colour, shadow,background-colour). Based on what the user selects the attributes will apply to a  element in the page.
I have to do it without JavaScript, only using HTML and CSS.
I've implemented this code but it does not seem to change the attributes of the  element.Can you please help me find a solution?

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

table {
  border: 3px double;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 3px double;
}

#text option[value="red"]:checked~h1 {
  color: red;
}

#text option[value="blue"]:checked~h1 {
  color: blue;
}

#shadow option[value="red"]:checked~h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#shadow option[value="blue"]:checked~h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

#background option[value="silver"]:checked~h1 {
  background-color: silver;
}

#background option[value="gold"]:checked~h1 {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">parameters</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="text">text</label></td>
      <td>
        <select id="text" name="text">
          <option value="red">red</option>
          <option value="blue">blue</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="shadow">shadow</label></td>
      <td>
        <select id="shadow" name="shadow">
          <option value="blue">blue</option>
          <option value="red">red</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="background">background</label></td>
      <td>
        <select id="background" name="background">
          <option value="silver">silver</option>
          <option value="gold">gold</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the selector [`:has()`](https://caniuse.com/css-has), this can be used to achieve what you are looking for. Here is an example, you can adjust the code to fit more inside your project:

```css
body:has(#color option[value="red"]:checked) h1 {
  color: red;
}

body:has(#color option[value="blue"]:checked) h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<form>
  <label for="color">Color</label>
  <select id="color">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </selec>
</form>
```

Just make sure that the element you are selecting in front of `:has(...)`, has to be a parent of the `<h1>` you want to alter.

Edit: To clarify, the `~` you used in your CSS does only select elements after the current one on the same level. Your `<h1>` is before all of it and also on another level.